# Unable to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> from Activity to Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

i try to pass my Array List from my MainActivity to one of my Fragments and tried the following:
Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements qr_code.GetDataInterface {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getDataList() {
        return contactList;
    }
}
```

And in my Fragment:

```
 public interface GetDataInterface {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getDataList();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        sGetDataInterface= (GetDataInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement GetDataInterface Interface");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(sGetDataInterface != null){
            mData = sGetDataInterface.getDataList();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: Is your `onResume` inside `onAttach`, or its just a typo?

Comment: `qr_code.GetDataInterface` doesn't look right unless your fragment is named `qr_code`. What do you mean with `doesn't work` ? Is the method call ? is the value null ? is the app crashing ? is the reference to the interface null ? Please add more info

Comment: i try to iterate over the Array List in my onResume() method and try to show content in a toast, but it doesnt show any content.